# Make box constantly fit screen and page content

Tags: css

I am new to CSS and I have been looking around and playing about with the code but I am just at a stage where I have no idea what to do.

I have a simple box at the top of a page. The idea is that at all times this box will be across the top of the screen and will always meet the edges (left and right sides). Here is what I have so far;

```
body
{
background-color:#E8E8E8;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#topbar
{
width:100%;
height:50px;
background-color:#fff;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.10);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.10);
box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.10);
}

#mainbodybox
{
margin:auto;
margin-top:150px;
width:1500px;
height:500px;
background-color:#fff;
}


<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fc_style.css">
<body>

<div id="topbar"></div>

<div id="mainbodybox"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Now this works fine, EXCEPT, when the window of the browser is resized to smaller than the width of mainbodybox it causes horizontal scroll to become available, which again I guess is fine but when you scroll it breaks the topbar and no longer fits to the edge of the screen, how can this be fixed?

Also as an extra question, as for the mainbodybox similarly it should be displayed in relation with the width of the window/screen size but only to a certain extent. For example I would wish it to only have a minimum dimension to correctly fit a 1024x768 size and then a maximum one of something like 1280x1024. If smaller than 1024x768 then the scroll would appear and if larger than 1280x1024 then simply space would just keep expanding the box.

I'm sorry for all the text but I'm just not good to do these things at the moment

Thanks in advance for any help, it's greatly appreciated

Comment: can you post some of your html or a codepen demo?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Fvahu/  Does this do what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `max-width` to your CSS

```
#mainbodybox
{
margin:auto;
margin-top:150px;
width:1500px;
max-width:100%;  <-- add this
overflow-x: scroll;  <-- add this
height:500px;
background-color:#fff;
}
```

You can add the `overflow` declaration that will give you the scroll ability. A more thorough approach would be to ensure your child elements do not exceed the width of the parent element, in this case `#mainbodybox`

Comment: Thank you for your response, this does indeed work. However, when you do this and make the window smaller than the edges of mainbodybox it won't let you scroll to view the edges?

Comment: Have you got an example, I don't quire follow what you mean

Comment: [link](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2je5y61&s=8#.U0Q37vldV8E)

If you see the picture, I've made the browser screen quite thin. However (imagining) content inside that mainbodybox I am not allowed to scroll across to the edges of that mainbodybox to view all that content?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **min-width** and **max-width** rules to do this, if you want to remove the scroll bar `max-width: 100%;` will mean **#mainbodybox** adapts to the width of the viewport as the browser window is re-sized. using width rules with a percentage usually mean the element is bound to the maximum width of a parent container in your case the parent container is the body tag, but as it has no width specified it will default to the width of the viewport (viewable area of the browser window).

As for your second question, both these rules can be used with a variety of units e.g. pixels, percentages, em etc. So you can set *min-width to 1024px* and *max-width to 1280px* respectively.

Here's a codepen with the min & max rules setup: [codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xnLtA/)

Comment: This has already been suggested nearly an hour ago!? It's worth coming up with an alternative suggestion or not bothering

Comment: The original poster didn't answer both parts of the question -further his answer was edited to include the information about parent container width after I posted my answer. I don't have enough rep to comment on his post, so I wrote a new answer which at the time had more detail than available answers & didn't ignore a second question.